# How can I collect a particular type of data from all of the different existing websites

Tags: data-analysis, data-collection

suppose i want to collect all the weather information of all city.

i don't want to collect it manually or even from a particular weather API. All i want from all kind of existing websites. i want to collect those data. then i want to process those data, according to my requirement. I want to create a **bot** who can dynamically read all data from existing websites.

I am beginner, please advice me how can i do this job. Also tell me whether is it can be possible or not.

Comment: You're question is very broad. To start, I'd just create a list of all the weather API's I want to request data from and create an algorithm to average the data out.

Comment: basically my intention is to create a intelligence bot....i dont want to create a list of weather API's manually.....automatically it searchers the web...and categorized that who are provides the weathers info.....then from them it shows me result

Comment: How do you think you would go about that? I would collect the weather API's manually.

Comment: so its not possible...?

Comment: Well, it's possible, it's just that the work involved to create the technology to search the web for weather API's seems a little not-worth-it.

Comment: its only example of weather......my intention is so big.....collect vast info from web

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do two things: find multiple API's and then collect data from them and average it all out. I would suggest first looking at three or four APIs, and then focusing on an averaging-algorithm.

Comment: please tell me how can i do this.....

Comment: Tell me how you would do it please

Comment: say an example. theirs are lot of website provides hotel booking information and also provides price..i don't want to list all this kind of website manually...all i want to create an algorithm....which searches in the web ....and show me all hotel rooms price for different websites for a particular location. for price comparison purpose...

Comment: That's a difficult task, but if you're up to it, you can do it...